# Recursively output a php array in nested div?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with a data structure like below

```
$array = array(
   'someKey' => array(
       'id' => 1,
       'string' => 'some key',
       'someKey2' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'string' => 'some key two',
            'someKeyThree' => array(
                 'id' => 1,
                 'string' => 'some key three',
            ,
       ),
   ),
   'someOtherKey' => array(

   ),
);
```

What I would like to do is out every array as a nested `div p` structure,

```
<div>
    <p>someKey</p> // key of first array value
    <div>
          <p>someKey2</p>
          <div>
                 <p>SomeKeyThree</p>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($this->getData(), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST));`

and using that but I am having trouble as the end tag for `div` never ends up right. Also once the `iterator` reaches the bottom of an array with no array to go into I want it to stop iterating completely.

THanks

Comment: Your wanted HTML structure is invalid.

Comment: Well make it divs instead then with p, ill change it

Comment: Do you want to generate nested UL element with every array element in your array?

Comment: Yes if possible, the documentation for `arrayIterator` is not the best I am having trouble with. I would also like the iteration to stop if no array is found within that iteration, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call a function recursively.

```
function printUl($arr){
$output = "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
  if (is_array($val)){
    $output .= printUl($val);
    continue;
  }
  else{
  $output .= "<li>".$val."</li>"

  }
$output .= "</ul>";
return $output;
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't line 4 and 5 read if (is_array($val)){ $output .= printUl($val); ... ?? i.e. $val not $key ($key will always be a scalar)